# How to iterate an array cleanly PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Hello im having a hard time iterating my array. I don't know what to use a simple `foreach` or with a `foreach` with `$key`. I tried with `key` but im having an error of:

**Illegal string offset 'payroll_employee_company_id' (View: /var/www/html/digimahouse/resources/views/member/payrollreport/loan_summary_table.blade.php)**

How can i iterate it successfully?

here's my array
[image]

here's my foreach

```
 @foreach($totals as $key => $total)
      @if($total['payroll_employee_company_id'] == $comid->payroll_company_id)
        <tr class="total">
          <td class="text-center"><strong>TOTAL</strong></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center">{{$total['loan_total']}}</td>
          <td class="text-center">{{$total['total_total_payment']}}</td>
          <td class="text-center">{{$total['total_remaining_balance']}}</td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
        </tr>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

here's my controller

```
public function loan_summary()
{
    $data["page"] = "Loan Summary";
    $data["_loan_data"] = PayrollDeductionController::get_deduction($this->shop_id());
    $data["_company"] = Payroll::company_heirarchy(Self::shop_id());//Tbl_payroll_company::where("shop_id", Self::shop_id())->where('payroll_parent_company_id', 0)->get();
    $data['totals'] = $this->get_totals_loan_summary($data);

    return view("member.payrollreport.loan_summary", $data);
}
```

Comment: Where is `$totals`  comming from? Post it...

Comment: @B001 what you mean by **BTW: get rid of using @** ??

Comment: That's a laravel syntax. In the controller.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam totally my bad...

Comment: which one are you looping on ? totals inside array or the whole array which contains page,_company , _load_dataand totals ?

Comment: @MahdiYounesi the whole array.

Comment: Please show the controller method.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin i edited my question.

Comment: @nethkennnnn thanks. Also, please show full output for `{{ dd($totals) }}`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin the picture in questions is the result sir.

Comment: @nethkennnnn it looks like result for `dd($data)` not for `{{ dd($totals) }}`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin i exactly put the `{{ dd($totals) }}` sir and that's the exact same thing in the picture

Comment: @nethkennnnn if it's true, my answer will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said the picture is result for `{{ dd($totals) }}`. In this case, do this:

```
@foreach($totals['totals'] as $key => $total)
      @if($total['payroll_employee_company_id'] == $comid->payroll_company_id)
        <tr class="total">
          <td class="text-center"><strong>TOTAL</strong></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center">{{$total['loan_total']}}</td>
          <td class="text-center">{{$total['total_total_payment']}}</td>
          <td class="text-center">{{$total['total_remaining_balance']}}</td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
        </tr>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Can you put an explaination why it worked sir? I want to understand my mistake.

Comment: @nethkennnnn you just nest it twice. You can also do something like this `array_marge($data, $this->get_totals_loan_summary($data));` to make your previous code work in the view.

Answer (score 0):

you foreach was not on the correct array

```
 @foreach($data['totals'] as $key => $total)
  @if($total['payroll_employee_company_id'] == $comid->payroll_company_id)
    <tr class="total">
      <td class="text-center"><strong>TOTAL</strong></td>
      <td class="text-center"></td>
      <td class="text-center"></td>
      <td class="text-center">{{$total['loan_total']}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{$total['total_total_payment']}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{$total['total_remaining_balance']}}</td>
      <td class="text-center"></td>
    </tr>
@endif
```

@endforeach

Comment: He actually returns `$totals` variable, not `$data`. That's how the `view()` helper works.